# Merge two columns of equal length into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas DataFrame containing multiple columns. What I am trying to accomplish is to combine/stack the values of two of the columns into one column  stacking the values of each column one row after another other (unfortunate this requirement prevents me from using a union like solution). The content of the other remaining columns can just be duplicated. Any help is extremely appreciated

```
#Current DataFrame
print(df)
Stock Ticker    Index Ticker    Price   Date
AAPL            INDX            100     12/31/2018 8:57  
GOOG            RSL             123     12/31/2018 8:57
GM              COMP            90      12/31/2018 8:57
MMM             NIKK            340     12/31/2018 8:57
INVD            EUR             30      12/31/2018 8:57 

#Desired results
print(df2)
Stock and Bench   Price   Date
AAPL              100     12/31/2018 8:57
INDX              100     12/31/2018 8:57
GOOG              123     12/31/2018 8:57
RSL               123     12/31/2018 8:57
GM                90      12/31/2018 8:57
COMP              90      12/31/2018 8:57
MMM               340     12/31/2018 8:57
NIKK              340     12/31/2018 8:57
INVD              30      12/31/2018 8:57
EUR               30      12/31/2018 8:57
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the price and date columns as index and stack the stock and ticker. Finally some clean up using reset_index.

```
df.set_index(['Date', 'Price'])[['Stock Ticker','Index Ticker']].stack()\
.reset_index(2,drop = True).reset_index(name = 'Stock and Bench')


    Date    Price   Stock and Bench
0   12/31/2018 8:57 100 AAPL
1   12/31/2018 8:57 100 INDX
2   12/31/2018 8:57 123 GOOG
3   12/31/2018 8:57 123 RSL
4   12/31/2018 8:57 90  GM
5   12/31/2018 8:57 90  COMP
6   12/31/2018 8:57 340 MMM
7   12/31/2018 8:57 340 NIKK
8   12/31/2018 8:57 30  INVD
9   12/31/2018 8:57 30  EUR
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) setting `Date` and `Price` as `id_vars`:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Price'], 
         value_name='Stock and Bench')
         .drop('variable', axis=1))

         Date        Price     Stock and Bench
0  12/31/2018/8:57    100            AAPL
1  12/31/2018/8:57    123            GOOG
2  12/31/2018/8:57     90              GM
3  12/31/2018/8:57    340             MMM
4  12/31/2018/8:57     30            INVD
5  12/31/2018/8:57    100            INDX
6  12/31/2018/8:57    123             RSL
7  12/31/2018/8:57     90            COMP
8  12/31/2018/8:57    340            NIKK
9  12/31/2018/8:57     30             EUR
```

Or using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames='Ticker', i = 'index', 
                j = 'num', suffix='\w+')
                .reset_index(drop=True)
                .rename({'Ticker':'Stock and Bench'}, axis=1))

        Date         Price Stock and Bench
0  12/31/2018-8:57    100   AAPL
1  12/31/2018-8:57    123   GOOG
2  12/31/2018-8:57     90     GM
3  12/31/2018-8:57    340    MMM
4  12/31/2018-8:57     30   INVD
5  12/31/2018-8:57    100   INDX
6  12/31/2018-8:57    123    RSL
7  12/31/2018-8:57     90   COMP
8  12/31/2018-8:57    340   NIKK
9  12/31/2018-8:57     30    EUR
```